# mouse focus on a textbox not getting updated in wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox

I have two textboxes. The values are bind from properties:

```
<TextBlock Text="Input 1" Margin="3,3,3,3" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#FFF4E7CA"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Processing.Input1}" Margin="3,3,6,3" FontWeight="Normal"/>
    
<TextBlock Text="Input 2" Margin="3,3,3,3" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#FFF4E7CA"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Processing.Input2}" Margin="3,3,6,3" FontWeight="Normal"/>
```

After changing the values in the first textbox, I press on "Save" button. the value of the Textbox1 will be not updated on the saved result. Only if I move the mouse focus from textbox 1 after editing to Textbox 2. then the result got updated. How can I get the textbox updated to the property immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBox` by default updates the binding source on [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx). It seems that `TextBox` does not lose the focus by pressing the "Save" button.

You can update the binding source immediately after every change with:

```
Text="{Binding Processing.Input1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

or update the binding source explicit on "Save" button click:

```
// textBox1 is your Textbox1
BindingExpression be = textbox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
be.UpdateSource();
```